# join, group and afterwards count SQL statement

Tags: sql

I am currently working through some excerises in a book and found a task that I am not able to solve.

The task is to print out every Course that is less than 50% filled.

I need to print out the CourseId, CourseName, Time and how filled the Course is. (I can calculate how filled a Course is by counting the number of people in a course divided by the number of max allowed people in a course times 100; (Count(CustomerIds) / MaxCustomers) * 100)

the tables look like this:

```
Customers
-----------
CustomerId FK
CourseId FK

Course
-----------
CourseId PK
CourseTypeId FK
Time 

CourseType
------------
CourseTypeId PK
CourseName
MaxCustomers
```

Here is my current, not working approach:

```
SELECT course.CourseId, 
courseType.CourseName, 
course.Date, 
(COUNT(customers.CourseId) / courseType.MaxCustomers) * 100 as 'Fill in %' 
FROM Customers customers 
INNER JOIN Course course 
ON customers.CourseId = course.CourseId 
INNER JOIN CourseType courseType 
ON course.CourseTypeId = courseType.CourseTypeId 
GROUP BY course.CourseId 
HAVING COUNT(customers.CourseId) / courseType.MaxCustomers) * 100 <= 50
```

Been working on this exercise for 4 hours now and cant seem to get it to work. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

Also you have to include all the columns in `GROUP BY` you are selecting without using `aggregate` function.

Try this:

```
SELECT course.CourseId,
         courseType.CourseName,
         course.Time,
         (COUNT (customers.CourseId) / courseType.MaxCustomers) * 100
            AS 'Fill in %'
    FROM Customers customers
    JOIN Course course ON customers.CourseId = course.CourseId
    JOIN CourseType courseType ON course.CourseTypeId = courseType.CourseTypeId
GROUP BY course.CourseId,courseType.CourseName,course.Time,courseType.MaxCustomers
HAVING COUNT(customers.CourseId) / courseType.MaxCustomers * 100 <= 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Having count instead of Where:

```
SELECT course.CourseId, courseType.CourseName, course.Date, (COUNT(customers.CourseId) / courseType.MaxCustomers) * 100 as 'Fill in %' from Customers customers inner join Course course on customers.CourseId = course.CourseId inner join CourseType courseType on course.CourseTypeId = courseType.CourseTypeId group by course.CourseId Having COUNT(customers.CourseId) / courseType.MaxCustomers) * 100 <= 50
```